# How to go back in an array and check the first non zero value - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array with values and I have the currently active value of the array. The active value is a middle value somewhere.I need to go back from the active array and get the index of the first non zero value.
And consider that I have a function to get the values before and after the active value.
For example:

```
myarray = [300,250,700,0,0,0,500(activeValue),700,300]
```

I need to start from active value and go backwards and check the first non zero value.How can I do this.Please help.

This is how I tried

```
for (i = previousPlayerSeat; i <= nextPlayerSeat; i--){
            if (this.seats[i] !== null){
                do {
                    this.lastPlayerToAct = i;
                }
                while (this.seats[i].public.chipsInPlay === 0)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What have your tried so far ? Would you mind adding your attempts of code to achive the desired results ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
let firstNonZeroValue;
for(let i = myarray.indexOf(value); i > 0; i--) {
    if(myarray[i] !== 0) {
       firstNonZeroValue = myarray[i];
       break;
    }
}

firstNonZeroValue && console.log(`Found a non-zero value: ${firstNonZeroValue}`);
```

Note that the most efficient way to find the first index matching a value in an unsorted array is to just walk through the list in order, which is O(n). So the big-O complexity of this solution is O(n) [for the index search] + O(n) [in case the nearest non-zero value is the first element of the array] = O(2n) = O(n).

Comment: Thank you this answer helped me to fix my issue. I had to use this method forward and backward.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wan't to get the first non-zero value before the active value. So on your `myarray` above, the `active` value is `500` — you want to get `700`.

You could do

```js
const activeValue = 500;
const myarray = [300, 250, 700, 0, 0, 0, 500, 700, 300];

// get active value's index
const activeValueIndex = myarray.findIndex((value) => value === activeValue);

// get the reversed section of array that  excludes
// active value and its subsequents
const arrayToSearch = myarray.slice(0, activeValueIndex).reverse();
// console.log(arrayToSearch); // [0, 0, 0, 700, 250, 300]

// get the first non zero from arrayToSearch
const firstNonZeroValue = arrayToSearch.find((value) => value !== 0);

console.log(firstNonZeroValue);
```